# short td content to match td wide?

Tags: html

i have problem in my table rows!

My html code

```
<table border=1 width=100%>
<tr>
<td>
My post subject
</td>
<td>
My post small content/description goes here , 
test small description , test small description , test small description
</td>
<td>
post auther
</td>
<td>
post date
</td>
</table>
```

if you minimize the screen

the td height will became doubly!

So i want make table height not affectable!

i think this is impossible!

So i have found trick in google gmail

they use this trick

they only show some of the td content!

for example:

my real td content is

```
My post small content/description goes here , 
test small description , test small description , test small description
```

if you minimized the screen

it will became shorted to

```
My post small content/description goes here , 
test small description
```

to match the td width!

i have taked one picture from google gmail before and after minimiz

and i have also taked one picture for my page before and after minimiz!

The google explation image:
[image]

My page image:
[image]

i think they done it by javescript!

because page contain no css codes!

--edit -- reply for joe

i tried your code and found new problem

[image]

please see pictures again and see my problem!

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can probably fake it with

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
    My post small content/description goes here , 
    test small description , test small description , test small description
</td>
```

Obviously you can define that as a CSS class or rule in a separate stylesheet, if you so wish. I've shown it inline for simplicity :)

Comment: Joe thank you very much but i got new problem , please see my edit